# How to check the diff between the last 2 pushed commits

Tags: github, github-actions, git-diff

So, I have a GitHub workflow that runs on push and checks for changes in a specific directory and runs a script if there are changes. However, with the current implementation (`git diff HEAD^ HEAD`), it only checks the diff between the last 2 commits. It is entirely possible that more than 1 commit was pushed so I am looking for a way through which I can compare the last 2 **pushed** commits.

Would be awesome if anyone  can help me with this!

Comment: "pushed commits" is not a concept in git, there is no record or log of it. Github may have a log of what was pushed but it is not available through your local git commands.

Comment: I see, is there any other alternative way to do so?

Comment: What about something like `git diff origin/master^ HEAD`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
on: 
  push:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          # checkout full tree
          fetch-depth: 0
      - run: |
          git diff ${{github.event.before}} ${{github.sha}}
```

As per [the docs on the `github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) and [the docs on the `push` webhook event data](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push) `{{github.event.before}}` is replaced by the commit SHA before the push. `{{github.sha}}` or `{{github.event.after}}` is replaced by the SHA of the latest commit that was pushed.